# How to configure a image pop up for android using eclipce?

Tags: android, eclipse, popup, imageview

I'm working with a list of ImageViews, while I would like to each one be clicked on, an image appear as a pop up.
Currently got a good result, but a lot of work, I created a new xml file for each image, so using onclicklistener, every time I click on ImageView, open another layout xml, but that I would like just open a pop up image.
Can anyone help me?

Here is may xml:

res/layout/main.xml

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="353dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:text="@string/popup1" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:text="@string/popup2" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button3"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:text="@string/popup3" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button4"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:text="@string/popup4" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/button5"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:text="@string/popup5" />
   </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   </FrameLayout>
```

res/layout/aperitivos

```
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/ivcarnes"
   android:layout_width="364dp"
   android:layout_height="410dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:contentDescription="@string/panecestino"
   android:src="@drawable/panecestinoim" />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/btclose"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="right"
   android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
   android:text="@string/close"
   android:textStyle="bold"/>
   </FrameLayout>
```

Here is my code:
Main.java

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.*;

   public class Main extends Activity {

   Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

            button1 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button4 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button5 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button5);

   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View Arg0) {

   Intent testegrafico = new
   Intent(Main.this,Aperitivos.class);
   Main.this.startActivity(testegrafico);
   Main.this.finish();
   }});
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }}
```

Aperitivos.java

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.*;

   public class Aperitivos extends Activity {

   Button btclose;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.aperitivos);

   btclose = (Button)
   findViewById(R.id.btclose);

   btclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View Arg0) {

   Intent testegrafico = new
   Intent(Aperitivos.this,Main.class);
   Aperitivos.this.startActivity(testegrafico);
   Aperitivos.this.finish();
   }
   });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package br.com.example.locandaristorante;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

public class Main extends Activity {

Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            button1 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button4 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button5 = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button5);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
     View popupView = new View(Main.this);
     final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.panecestinoim);

     popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
     popupWindow.setHeight(600);
     popupWindow.setWidth(400);      
     popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
     popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
     popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });



     popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.button1), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);



                }
            });
}}
```

Comment: hi Akhil, tks for your answer...but i m a litle confuse!

Comment: hi Akhil, tks for your answer...but i m a litle confuse!
i will put may code here and please, say what should i do!

Comment: I have put my code above! I appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: Tks again for your help...
But i just tried to use your code, and the eclipse came up with two errors "The method setContentView(View) in the type PopupWindow is not applicable for the arguments (int)" and "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PopupWindow"...
Anyway, i think that with this code, i will continue to have to use a layout.xml, when i don't want to, i real want to use just a image showing as a pop up, that can be at my drawable. 
I appreciate your atention and i keep hoping that you can help me.
Tks

Comment: the error "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PopupWindow" still. (and you still use the res\layout\aperitivos.xml that i dont want to, i want to use image from my drawable).

Comment: just to clarify, I put the xml, just to show how I am doing now, but I do not want to use it, I want to use an image from the drawable.

Comment: tks again, your skills are being very helpful...
if is not ask too much, i just need one more thing, that when the image will be touched, it disappear.

Comment: do some googling for setTouchInterceptor for PopupWindow (you need to dismiss it in onTouch menthod)..thx

Comment: I have edited my code with the final results, its working good now!